# Adding ActionBarSherlock as a library makes my project lose its R class and generally freak out

Tags: android, eclipse, android-actionbar, android-resources, android-library

My app uses `ActionBarActivity` and `ViewPager` and I'd like to extend support to devices older than 3.0 (level 11 and below). However, when I try to add ActionBarSherlock as a library, my project goes to hell. Every reference to my projects `R` class is complained about.

I've read that this can be caused by multiple `android-support-v4.jar` files in the project. However, I seem to have a few and I'm not sure exactly how I should clean things up.

I think the easiest way is to post a picture of my Package Explorer. What do I need to delete or change to get my project working so that I can implement ActionBarSherlock and support older Android versions? Thanks!

Also, an [Imgur link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNn1c.png).

[image]

Comment: use appcompat from the support library instead of actionbarsherlock. its just a suggestion.

Comment: @Raghunandan, my activity currently extends `ActionBarActivity (android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity)`. Does that not mean that I'm using the `appcompat` support library? I'm still getting errors when I call `getActionView()` and `getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(int)`.  Can I use appcompat and still support these functions?

Comment: you should take a clear look on your `xml` files, whether its layout, Manifest or other `.xml` files. Fix any kind of `syntax` error in `xml` and then clean your project will return your R.java back.

Answer (score 0):

After some searching, I found a solution that appeared to work.

My project was complaining about my `getActionView` and `getActionBar` methods. This was solved by...

- Replace `getActionView` with `MenuItemCompat.getActionView`.
- Replace `getActionBar` with `getSupportActionBar`.